# datetime.datetime.strptime().date() converting date to wrong month

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am encountering a simple error thats bugging me. I am passing `date` in `string` format and then converting it to `date` using `datetime`. Here is my code:

```
import datetime
def room(book_date):
    date_converted = datetime.datetime.strptime(book_date, '%Y-%M-%d').date()

    print(date_converted)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    room('2018-08-07')
```

The print statement prints `2018-01-07` while it should be `2018-08-07`. No matter what date I pass the month is always `01`. Why is this coming in this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%M` is the code for *minutes*, not for the month. Use `%m`, lowercase:

```
date_converted = datetime.datetime.strptime(book_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Because you didn't parse out a month, the default is used (1 for midnight January 1st, 1900).

Demo:

```
>>> book_date = '2018-08-07'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(book_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 7, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(book_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2018, 8, 7)
>>> print(_)
2018-08-07
```

If you don't focus on just the date, the error is perhaps easier to spot:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(book_date, '%Y-%M-%d')
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 7, 0, 8)
```

That 8 in the minute position should be a red flag.

Comment: aah! I didn't took notice of that. Thanks!